# Цифры + символы в Toast

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Имеется:
**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="keyboard_error">Какой то текст!</string>
</resources>
```

В основном классе:

```
String num = "123";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.keyboard_error + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Если в `Toast` использую только `R.string.keyboard_error`, то выводится соответствующий текст из strings.xml, а если я добавляю к сообщению цифры `R.string.keyboard_error + num`, то выводится сообщение вида 2131099698123 (последние цифры 123 это `num`). Подскажите как правильно вывести текст из `strings.xml` + текст из переменной `num`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо сначала получить значение ресурса по его идентификатору.

```
String message = getResources().getString(R.string.keyboard_error);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Обычно, когда вы передаёте индентификатор ресурса методу makeText, он это делает за вас. Ваша попытка прибавить число к идентификатору привело к тому, что в makeText передалось числовое значение самого идентификатора + значение переменной `num`, вместо строкового значения ресурса, на который идентификатор указывал.

Comment: Спасибо! А можете объяснить, почему так происходит и извлекать строку надо именно таким способом?

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Надеюсь, что получилось понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее пользоваться параметрами (нумерованными), ведь добавляемый текст бывает не только в конце:

```
<resources>
    <string name="keyboard_error">Какой то текст! %1$s. Еще какой-то текст... А тут какое-то число %2$d, и еще может быть текст %3$s...</string>
</resources>
```

В основном классе:

```
String str = "foo";
int num = 123;
String anotherStr = "bar";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toast.makeText(this, 
        getString(R.string.keyboard_error, str, num, anotherStr),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```